# Powershell script to match condition of excel cell values

Tags: excel, powershell

I am novice programmer of powershell, I am trying to do excel search and change of format and font option. Here is the snippet were I am trying to search for the word "PASSED" and change the color to green and bold, currently the code does exits out without changing as expected what is wrong in this which I could not figure out, need help in this regards.

```
  $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excel.Visible = $false
    $excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")
    $sheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet

    $xlCellTypeLastCell = 11

    $used = $sheet.usedRange 
    $lastCell = $used.SpecialCells($xlCellTypeLastCell) 
    $row = $lastCell.row # goes to the last used row in the worksheet

    for ($i = 1; $i -lt $row.length; $i++) {
    If ($sheet.cells.Item(1,2).Value() = "PASSED") {
            $sheet.Cells.Item(1,$i+1).Font.ColorIndex = 10
            $sheet.Cells.Item(1,$i+1).Font.Bold = $true
              }
    }

    $workbook.SaveAs("C:\output.xlsx")
    $workbook.Close()
```

Input(test.xlsx) file has the following

```
Module | test | Status
ABC      a      PASSED
```

Its quiet a huge file with different status of each unit test.

Comment: Also `Value` is a Property not a method, you should remove the `()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row` is a string containing the last row number, comparing to it's `Length` property in the `for` loop will land you in trouble since it'll give you the length of the string itself.

Change it to:

```
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $row; $i++) {
```

In the `if` statement inside the loop, there's another problem: `=`

In order to compare two values for equality, use the `-eq` operator instead of `=` (`=` is only for assignment):

```
if ($sheet.cells.Item($i,2).Value() -eq "PASSED") {
    $sheet.Cells.Item(1,$i+1).Font.ColorIndex = 10
    $sheet.Cells.Item(1,$i+1).Font.Bold = $true
}
```

Lastly, Excel cell references are not zero-based, so `Item(1,2)` will refer to the cell that in your example has the value "test" (notice how it takes a row as the first parameter, and a column as the second). Change it to `Item(2,3)` to test against the correct cell, and transpose the cell coordinates inside the if block as well.

You may want to update the `for` loop to reflect this as well:

```
for ($i = 2; $i -le $row; $i++) {
    if ($sheet.cells.Item($i,3).Value() = "PASSED") {
        $sheet.Cells.Item($i,3).Font.ColorIndex = 10
        $sheet.Cells.Item($i,3).Font.Bold = $true
    }
}
```

Comment: Even after adding -eq as mentioned it did not work as well there were no errors which is causing hard to debug the code, could you please explain a little more as to why it did not work and provide suitable solution.

Comment: Yes I should have seen the for loop, with your suggestion it worked. Thanks