# how to get a for each go over individual cell in excel?

Tags: powershell

I am new to PS and I have this script and I want to go through the rows but I want to get the value of a cell individually and then the next one and so on, so I can do if value1 -eq something do this or do that 
so far I have this:

```
    #Install-module PSExcel -Scope CurrentUser
#Get-command -module psexcel

$path = "\\srf201002\Sistemas Liberaciones\Hilda Ruiz\QA Sistemas\Borrador\Azure Pipeline\Prueba.xlsx"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($path)
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.worksheets.Item(1)
$totalNoOfRecords = ($WorkSheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
Write-Output $totalNoOfRecords



$people = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
$i=1
foreach ($item in $WorkSheet)
{

$op=$Worksheet.Rows.Item(5).Columns.Item(7).Text
$people.add($op) | Out-Printer #I don't want to see the output

}


Write-Output $people
```

and all it does is print the cell I tell it to print

how can I make it to loop through 1- 7 and then go to the next row? 
Thank you for all the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are similar examples of this type of use case all over the web, just search for them using your use case. Thus getting results like...

'[PowerShell validate excel cells every row](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20validate%20execel%20cells%20every%20row&form=ANNTH1&refig=04b824cc56d74052a9d2817b8ac62de9&sp=-1&pq=PowerShell%20validate%20excel%20cells%20every%20row&sc=0-42&qs=n&sk=&cvid=04b824cc56d74052a9d2817b8ac62de9)'

```
### Read excel file line by line

# Open excel file and use specific sheet
    $objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $objExcel.Visible=$false
    $WorkBook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strFileName)
    if ($strSheetName -eq "")
    {
    $worksheet = $WorkBook.sheets.Item(1)
    }
    else
    {
    $worksheet = $WorkBook.sheets.Item($strSheetName)
    }
# loop for each row of the excel file
    $intRowMax = ($worksheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
    for($intRow = 2 ; $intRow -le $intRowMax ; $intRow++)
    {
    $codeName  = $worksheet.cells.item($intRow,$intCode).value2
    $author    = $worksheet.cells.item($intRow,$intAuth).value2
    $createDate= $worksheet.cells.item($intRow,$intCrDt).value2
    $validate  = $worksheet.cells.item($intRow,$intVali).value2
    $validDate = $worksheet.cells.item($intRow,$intVlDt).value2
    } 
    $WorkBook.close()
    $objexcel.quit()
```

Of course, you'll need to tweak the above to fit your use case. Especially if you need to dynamically discover the number of columns and act on those.

So, my tweak to the one above to handle such a dynamic column use case would be something like this...

```
# Mine
Clear-Host
$strFileName = 'D:\Temp\Test.xlsx'
$strSheetName = 'Sheet1'

# Open excel file and use specific sheet
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$objExcel.Visible = $false

$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($strFileName)

if ($strSheetName -eq '') { $worksheet = $WorkBook.sheets.Item(1) }
else { $worksheet = $WorkBook.sheets.Item($strSheetName) }

# loop for each row of the excel file
$intRowMax = ($worksheet.UsedRange.Rows).count

for($intRow = 1 ; $intRow -le $intRowMax ; $intRow++)
{
    "Showing cell data for row#$intRow"
    $WorkBook.Sheets.Item(1).Rows($intRow).value2
} 

$WorkBook.close()
$objexcel.quit()

# Shut down Excel
Get-Process -Name EXCEL -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Stop-Process -Force

# Results
<#
Showing cell data for row#1
Row1-1
Row1-2
Row1-3
Row1-4
Row1-5
Row1-6
Row1-7
Showing cell data for row#2
Row2-1
Row2-2
Row2-3
Row2-4
Row2-5
Row1-6
Row2-7
Showing cell data for row#3
Row3-1
Row3-2
Row3-3
Row3-4
Row3-5
Row3-6
Row3-7
#>
```

Again, just an example, as there are always many options do do X or Y thingy.

... and btw, your question could have been answered by these Q&A / posts.

[Powershell script to match the condition of excel cell values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719870/powershell-script-to-match-condition-of-excel-cell-values)

Or this one

[How to read cell data in excel and output to command prompt [closed]](https://serverfault.com/questions/62138/how-to-read-cell-data-in-excel-and-output-to-command-prompt)

Comment: thank you, I'll check them out and I'm sorry I swear I searched before posting this, but maybe I was searching the wrong query, thank you once again

Comment: No worries, it happens to all of us at one or more points in our efforts to get stuff done.